# Creating a Photo Stream

Tags: facebook, graph, photo

I want to use the graph api to create a photostream of all the users friends photo's. How do you create a thing like that using the graph api.   I guess in essence I want to create a chronological photo album of all my friends photos.

How should I go about accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by getting the user's friends using `/me/friends`. Then you can cycle through the list of friends and get their photos like:

`<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/{friend_id}/picture" />`

You can use a JavaScript library to do the animation...

Comment: That would work if I only needed their avatar images but I need their latest uploads,ordered by date.

Comment: You can get the friend's photos using a similar API call: `/{friend_id}/photos` but you will need to ask the user for the `friends_photos` permission too. You may need to order the results manually too.

Comment: As I feared no shortcuts here, already tried using the stream table in FQL also no great results.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by saving the entire image collection of a facebook user in the app's database and querying them `SORT BY datetime`.